# Is outlook smtp reliable to send activation emails?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, outlook, smtp

I have a community website going live for beta this week. Currently, i'm using `smtp.live.com` to send activation emails as i dont have enough money this month to buy email hosting. So i decided to use outlook as i got the perfect email address so users wont be bothered by it, i hope...

My question is whether outlook is reliable to send activation emails? any possibility they will block the account if i send email continuesly?

What would you have done in such a situation? Please help me...

Comment: I'd suggest asking non-programming questions on SUPERUSER.COM.

Comment: Have you looked at mailgun.com - email sending platform aimed at developers and which has a generous free tier (first 10,000 emails free very month). I'm not affiliated to Mailgun.

Answer (score 0):

outlook.com is just a web email service like many others. They expect that you will send and receive emails using it. How many emails - well i am not sure, they probably have some sort of acceptable use policy - maybe this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/microsoft-services-agreement will help. Certainly it would be normal to send 100's of emails a day, but perhaps not tens of thousands.

Also this [blog entry](http://www.outlook-apps.com/outlook-com-daily-limit-emails/) has a discussion on send limits at outlook.com stating initially there is a 300 per day cap, but that it is possible to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/), their Free Package includes 400 email free /day. It also have a .NET library (via Nuget) that can be use alongside System.Net.Mail.